# Nginx Passenger Node Application URI Rewrite

Tags: nginx, rewrite, phusion-passenger, node.js

I have a node application that accepts all routes starting at `/`. The Nginx / Passenger configuration for it is:

```
server {
    listen 8889;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        root /var/www/portal/public;
        passenger_enabled on;
        passenger_min_instances 1;
        passenger_app_env production;
    }

    location ~ /error/(.+) {
        alias /var/www/error-pages/$1;
    }
}
```

I want to move the application to run at `/portal` without changing anything about the node application. I've tried something like this without much luck:

```
server {
    listen 8889;
    server_name localhost;

    root /var/www/portal/public;

    location / {
        return 301 /client;
    }

    location /portal {
        passenger_base_uri /;
        passenger_app_root /var/www/portal;
        passenger_document_root /var/www/portal/public;
        passenger_min_instances 1;
        passenger_app_env production;
        passenger_enabled on;
    }

    location ~ /error/(.+) {
        alias /var/www/error-pages/$1;
    }
}
```

The problem is that the application continues to receive requests prefixed with `/portal` instead of `/`. I tried adding `rewrite` statements, but they do not seem to affect what Passenger passes into the application.

Answer (score 0):

Change `passenger_base_uri /;` to `passenger_base_uri /portal;`.

From **[the official documentation](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#PassengerBaseURI)** :

> **8.2.2. passenger_base_uri**
>
> Used to specify that the given URI is a distinct application that should be served by Phusion Passenger.

Comment: I tried that as well. No matter what I specify for `passenger_base_uri` the application always receives the request starting with `/client`.

Comment: @xmon Try `location ~ /portal(/.*)?$` form instead and add `alias /var/www/portal/public$1;` before passenger directives (let the base uri of my answer).